# PHP Myadmin call to undefined function PMA_SQP_parse()

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost

When working on my webpage, I reloaded twice to check the results after editing... and got this error when trying to acces my localhost database page:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function PMA_SQP_parse() in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Util.class.php on line 1126

When I google for this issue, I only find 6 results, and I don't think any of the 6 would resolve my issue.

Has anyone had this issue before? I've looked on the `PHPMyAdmin` page, for support.. but the only result is them saying I have to ask my issue here...

Comment: You found a bug! You have a problem! (http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4160/)

Comment: Too bad that post is 'out of date' .. I've found a solution... sortof... Will post it down below as an answer.

Comment: Take a look here: http://goo.gl/63URvF Helps every time :D

Comment: Well... I like the weird IT vooodoo :D reboot -> try again, didn't work... wait 5 minutes -> try again, works?  thanks though @Rizier123

Comment: Your welcome! I think you looked something like this 5 min's ago: http://goo.gl/vmLEfp

Comment: Haha, actually that's roughly what I'm looking like right now, some  PHP and MySQL code that should work correctly, but doesn't... queries returning nothing at all in PHP but the queries do run and return something in MySQL... haha ^^

Comment: @Gerwin: which phpMyAdmin version are you running?

Comment: I'm running XAMP 3.2.1 and PHPMyAdmin 4.0.9 @MarcDelisle

Comment: @Gerwin phpMyAdmin 4.0.9 is outdated; could not find a reference to XAMPP 3.2.1

Comment: I got past this error by stripping the URL down to the pypMyAdmin home page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, for anyone who is interested in a fix... for me rebooting my PC worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing session storage for your phpmyadmin domain